# Generic Entity/Collection Fetching with LLBLGen DataAccessAdapter?

Tags: c#, generics, llblgenpro, llblgen

I have a form, which needs to have drop downs (Text and Value) populated from a database I'm accessing with LLBLGen DataAccessAdapter.
I'm using Telerik, if this provides any additional useful information or options.

Is there a way to do this generically so that I can simply call something like:

```
DropDown.DataSource = GetEntityCollection<OrderEntity>();
```

or

```
DropDown.DataSource = GetEntityCollection(OrderEntity);
```

I was initially attempting to do this like seen below, but no version of this idea I've come across seems to account for my whole scenario.  Since I need the type to be passed in as a generic or parameter I can't use as the type that `EntityCollection<>` needs (which is EntityBase2).

```
public static object GetEntityCollection<T>()  //Or
{
    using (DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter(CONNECTION))
    {
        EntityCollection<typeof(T)> collection = new EntityCollection<typeof(T)>();
        try
        {
            adapter.FetchEntityCollection(collection, null);
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

If this is not possible directly, is there a better way to split this up to avoid rewriting as a much for every single database entity I need to fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static IEntityCollection2 GetEntityCollection<T>() where T : EntityBase2
{
    using (DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter())
    {
        IEntityCollection2 collection = new EntityCollection<T> ();
        try
        {
            adapter.FetchEntityCollection(collection, null);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Log Exception
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, however IME I've never had a situation where i would just  run a select * from EVERY lookup table without some type of table-specific filtering or sorting at a minimum.  For that reason i would think that having such a generic method would be less helpful than having a method specific to each drop down.